# Traffic density estimation using deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computational-statistics, computer-vision

I am working on a project implementing deep learning and computer vision to estimate the traffic density of any random given road segment/roundabout or intersection.
I am given a camera mounted on the drone, which will capture the traffic footage and I aim to extract vehicles and road scene (image segmentation) out of it in real-time to calculate the density.
The problem is that the original formula for calculating the traffic density is number of vehicles/unit length of road, while with the present method & resources, I could not measure the length but only the area that the vehicles and the road/ pavement cover. Is it possible for me to calculate the traffic density as area of vehicles/area of road? If not, can anyone suggest me a method measuring the length of the road by deep learning automatically on any road segment (straight/curve).
I have read many paper mentioning the approach of estimating the traffic flow rather than the density to get the traffic status. However, I found that it is impossible to infer from the traffic flow that whether the road is congested or not (flow = 0 could mean heavy traffic or no traffic at all). Also, some of them can measure the length of the road because they mount a static camera on the light post, which makes the background static and they can easily calculate the pixel length of the road manually. Alternatively, I am using the drone the get the traffic data autonomously at anywhere, so measuring the length of the road is impossible.